# Why is a class that is already marked [DataContract] not serializable when inheriting from ConfigurationElement?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a class which was decorated as [DataContract] with some properties decorated as [DataMember]. The class was serializable. When I change the class to inherit from ConfigurationElement and changed the properties to be [ConfigurationProperty] I get an error below. What are the ways to fix this? Do I need to implement ISerializable interface? Thanks for any suggestions.

```
[DataContract]
public class Setting : ConfigurationElement, ICloneable
{

    [DataMember]
    [ConfigurationProperty("type")]
    public string Type 
    {
        get { return (string)this["type"]; }
        set { this["type"] = value; }
    }
}
```

The error message says:

```
"Type 'Imaging.Setting' cannot inherit from a type that is not marked with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute.  Consider marking the base type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement' with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute, or removing them from the derived type."
```

Comment: As clearly indicated in the error message, the declaration of the " ConfigurationElement" class shall be precceded by "[DataContract]" or "[Serializable()]".

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3500523/2308106 has few tips on how you can approach your problem

Comment: Your code builds OK (except for the IClonable part which demands writing the Clone method) with .NET 4.0 and VS 2010.